# Get flutter pub get error, trying to build the open source flutter repository locally

Tags: flutter, repository, local

trying to build open source flutter repository locally got the following error in the cloned flutter directory: Expected to find project root in current working directory.
I have flutter installed in c:\flutter

Changed to the cloned Flutter directory, in my case: 'C:\Devl\Projects\Flutter\flutter'
ran: C:\Devl\Projects\Flutter\flutter>flutter pub get
got: Expected to find project root in current working directory.
Expected: Existing Flutter Command Line Interface to run from my Flutter installation